# Probability of at least one Heads in $5$ tosses

Tags: probability

I want to model the event, that a biased coin toss shows heads at least once in $5$ tosses. I know this can be calculated easily by $1-(1-p)^5$, however that is kind of boring. Lets name the event I am looking for $A$. Then $A$ should be a disjoint union of $A_n$, more precisely $A=\operatorname* {\cup}\limits_{n=1}^5A_n$, where $A_n$ is the event of getting exactly $n$ heads. This should mean that $P(A) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^5 P(A_n)$. Now, since I want to model a biased coin, lets say getting heads has the probability $p$ and tails $1-p$. Then $P(A_n)$ should give: $P(A_n)=(6-n)p^n(1-p)^{5-n}$. The reason I come up with this is that, for $n=1$, one has $5$ possibilities of getting at least one heads, then $4$ and so on. This however doesn't add up to the equation I gave above. Where is my mistake? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: $P(A_n)=\binom 6n p^n(1-p)^{5-n}$.

Comment: @lulu Could you explain to me please, how you come up with the formula? I don't really care about the formula, but much more about the idea, in order to be able to really understand it.

Comment: Your problem concerns a routine [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to which the standard analysis applies.

Comment: Note:  my expression contains a typo, a $6$ for a $5$.  It should have read $P(A_n)=\binom 5np^n(1-p)^{5-n}$.

Comment: @lulu yes, thank you, I know where I made a mistake.

Comment: You go wrong in your reasoning at the point where you write "then $4$". It's actually $5$ possibilities (you got that part correct), then $10,$ then $10$ again, then $5$, then $1$ (so for $n=5$ you are correct again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the flips are independent, the probability of a certain sequence of flips is the product of the probabilities of the individual flips. For example, the probability that my sequence of flips is $\mathrm{HHHTH}$ = $P(H)\cdot P(H)\cdot P(H) \cdot P(T) \cdot P(H) = p^4(1-p)^1$. The probability of any given sequence of $5$ flips containing $n$ Heads is $p^n(1-p)^{5-n}$.

There are $\binom 5n$ events in which $n$ Heads come up in a sequence of $5$ flips; for example, $\mathrm{HHTHH}$ and $\mathrm{HHHTH}$ both count as $A_4$. Thus $P(A_n) = \binom 5np^n(1-p)^{5-n}$